# Why does my image changes to a square PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So when I run this code the output.png becomes a circle (which should happen) but when it gets pasted to the background it becomes a square for some reason. I would like to know why this happens.

[output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0u0M.png)

[level.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofLM8.png)

```
  
  mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')

  output = ImageOps.fit(img, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
  output.putalpha(mask)

  output.save('output.png')

  bg = Image.open("background.png")
  bg.paste(output, (390, 50))
  bg.save("level.png")
```

Comment: Why have you removed the `import` statements and thereby made your code un-runable? Why haven't you provided all the images you open? What result did you expect? Thank you.

Comment: I already have the imports in the code but I didn't display it here. Also, I already provided the 2 images under my explanation message.

Comment: If you want people to help you, IMHO it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.paste` doesn't work with alpha channel from the pasted image (`output`), but you can specify `mask` parameter to `paste()` (see: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) directly:

```
mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')
output = ImageOps.fit(img, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
bg = Image.open("background.png")
bg.paste(output, (390, 50), mask=mask)
bg.save("level.png")
```

no need to put alpha into `output` image either.